# Is it a good idea to add methods to Scala case classes

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

Case classes are suppose to be algebraic types, therefore some people are against adding methods to the case class. 
Can somebody please give an example for why it's a bad idea?

Comment: I don't think that this is a bad idea as long as your case class stays immutable and methods that you add are idempotent. In this case methods of case class can be viewed as functions with special namespace.

Comment: This would be a vastly better question if you'd point to some examples of people making that argument. People don't just go around saying "don't add methods to case classes", although some people might say that in a particular context, and it's going to be more or less defensible depending on that context.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those questions that leads to more questions. 
Following is my take on this.

Lets see what happens when a case class is defined,
The Scala compiler does the following,

- Creates a class and its companion object.
- Implements the `apply` method that you can use as a factory. This lets
  you create instances of the class without the `new` keyword.
- Prefixes all arguments, in the parameter list, with `val`. ie. makes it         immutable
- Adds implementations of `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString`
- Implements the `unapply` method, a case class supports `pattern matching`. This is important when you define an `Algebraic Data Type`.

  - Generates `accessors` for fields. Note that it does not generate "mutators"

Now as we can see case classes are not exact peers of the Java Beans. 
Case classes tend to represent `Datatype` more than it represents a `entity`.
I look at them as good friends of programmers in terms of the fact that it cuts down on the boiler plate of endless getters , override equals and hashcode methods etc.

Now coming to the question,

If you look at it from a functional programming standpoint then case classes are the way to go since you would looking at immutability , equality and you are sure that the `case class` represents a data structure. It is here that a lot of the times people programming in FP say to use them for ADTs.

If your case class has logic that works on the class's `state` then that makes it a bad choice for functional programming.

I prefer to use case classes for scenarios where i am sure that i need a class to represent a datastructure because thats where i get the help of auto generated methods and the added advantage of `patter-matching`. When i program in a OO way with side effects ,mutable state i use `class` .

Having said that there still could be scenarios where you could have a case class with `utlity` methods. I just think those chances are less.